# Datatype to use with parameter to procedure that is numeric (19,5)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Have a stored procedure being called from a SSIS 2016 package.  One of the parameters is type NUMERIC (19,5).  The SSIS variable that will be used to populate this parameter is defined as Decimal.

Most of the time, this seems to work fine, but in one case it was causing errors downstream.  So I fired up sql profiler to watch was being sent over.

Sure enough, instead of 184.96 as I seen in SSIS at debug time, was being sent over as 184.96000671386719 huh ?  Where are those extra digits coming from?

What is even stranger, is in the SQL statement which via SSIS is being executed via sp_executesql (as seen in profiler), that parameter in question is defined as datatype REAL.

What is the best datatype to supply a stored procedure parameter that is defined as NUMERIC(19,5) and in the case above, where are those extra digits coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the REAL datatype is being used, that is what is causing the extra digits, since REAL is equivalent to FLOAT and is not a precise datatype.

The SSIS equivalent to the numeric datatype is `DT_NUMERIC, «precision», «scale»`.   If that is how you have declared your variable, then the package must be converting it to REAL `(DT_R4)` in some part of the package that you aren't showing us.

Comment: Yep, no sooner than I posted this, I realized the actual parameter mapping where this variable was being mapped to, was actually trying to shove it in a FLOAT.   Arrrgh.